# gnuplot how to give column number to plot dynamically?

Tags: syntax, gnuplot

I am automating a task to create small graphs using gnuplot. And I need to pass the column number from the datafile that is to be plotted

```
pfile=system("echo $file")
colnum=system("echo $colnum")

plot pfile using 4:(column(colnum)) title "slot1"
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`colnum` is being exported earlier as `export colnum=2`

I am getting error at the highlighted part. I tried using export/fetch by system command, but it didn't work either
e.g. I tried `4:colnum`, got similar error

```
"./12.gnuplot.helper.pg", line 29: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points    
plot pfile using 4:(column(colnum)) title "slot1"   
                                                ^   
"./12.gnuplot.helper.pg", line 29: x range is invalid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that one has to do `colnum=int(system("echo $colnum"))` so that the variable `colnum` is interpreted as an integer and not a string

Answer (score 4):

You could also pass the column number via command line

```
gnuplot -e "colnum=$colnum" script.gp
```

and your `script.gp` contains

```
plot pfile using 4:(column(colnum))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried this, but it gives a similar error.

Comment: I tested it and it works fine. Note, that you must *not* have quotes around `$colnum`. Its all about integer vs. string.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative to @EWCZ's answer. Any variable initialized using the `system` command is treated as a string: in your case, `colnum="2"` (with quotes). You can transform it to an integer by adding zero:

```
# first option
plot pfile using 4:(column(colnum+0))

# second option
colnum = system("echo $colnum") + 0
plot pfile using 4:(column(colnum))
```

---

As a side note, your task could be more flexible (easier to automate) by using @Christoph's answer; better if you have `gnuplot 5.0` because you can [pass arguments to a gnuplot script directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31815067/2174266)