# Calculations using variable columns - gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to multiply 2 columns, where the index of one of the columns is given as a variable. I tried to multiply column `2` with column `ind` as shown below:

```
do for [j=1:4]{
    ind = (j-1)*5+1
    plot '../out/coeff.dat' using 1:($2*$ind) notitle with lines
}
```

I get this error: `Column number expected`.

I guess that the error might be in the usage of `$ind` as using a numerical value, eg: `1:($2*$3)` or simply `1:ind` works fine.

What is the correct syntax to perform arithmetic operation with a variable column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `column()` argument for that:

```
plot '../out/coeff.dat' using 1:($2*column(ind)) notitle with line
```

I tested on `gnuplot` 5.2 and it worked as expected. Also see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811596/gnuplot-how-to-give-column-number-to-plot-dynamically). Hope it helps!